# Can no longer log in after trying to change name of my home folder in Mac OS X

Tags: osx

I'm on OS X 10.10.5

I tried to change the name of my home folder and account using the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548). I followed them to the "T".

I made a temporary admin account to make the change from called temp. After changing the account name, home directory, and full name I can't log in to my old account anymore. It's still listed in system preferences, but I am not given the option to log in to the account in system preferences. What gives? I even went back through and changed the home folder, account name, and full name back to the original values with no luck. I didn't back my files up, but it looks like all my files are still there I just can't log in. How can I get back into that account?

Something that did just cross my mind is I had a software update pending on my old account before I restarted (I believe it wanted to upgrade to El Capitan). Is it possible that my old account performed that software update when I restarted and now I cannot log in to the account because of some software incompatibility between accounts? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you home directory still exists, you should back it up, delete the account you can't login to, remake that account, and replace its home directory with the one you backed up.